# Как вывести на экран изображение base64?

Tags: изображения, base64, html, php, canvas

Как правильно вывести на экран/показать изображение в формате base64?

[Пример изображения](http://pastie.org/pastes/9526400/text).

Если вывести

> `<img src="тут код из ссылки">`

то не выводит, типа битая.

Но если использовать сервис http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ , он выводит нормально, значит дело не в данных, как понимаю.

Как решить проблему?

(изображение изначально получено через js/canvas(toDataUrl))

Answer (score 3):

Вот так попробуй

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```